# Why cant I build this maven as an executable

Tags: maven, rdf, semantic-web, word-embedding

The maven project for [rdf2vec](http://data.dws.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/rdf2vec/code/RDF2Walks.zip) builds an executable without any errors however the jar file throws "no main manifest attribute" error.

My attempt to resolve it:

Replace the following snippet :

`<manifest>
    <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
</manifest>`

with :

`<manifest>
    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
    <mainClass>walks.WalkGenerator</mainClass>
</manifest>`

Thereby making WalkGenerator as the default main class for the entire package. 
This sadly, does not do the trick.

Another issue is that I cant find the MANIFEST file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `maven-jar-plugin` to set main class for you jar

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>                              
        <mainClass>walks.WalkGenerator</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @rajiv.v.i, please mark answer as accepted then so that others will not spend their time on it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the changes mentioned above, one has add the following dependencies to get the executable running:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactid>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```